# What reference should I add to fix GetPixel error?

Tags: c#

In my attempt to write some code, I received this error:

> Error 1 'System.Drawing.Image' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetPixel' and no extension method 'GetPixel' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Drawing.Image' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know what I need to do?

```
//Create a Image-Object on which we can draw
Image bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
//Create the Graphics-Object to paint on the Bitmap
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.White);
g.DrawString(randomString, myFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(0, 0));
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
bmp.Save(@"CAPTCHA.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

var backgroundPixels = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.White)
      backgroundPixels++;
```

Comment: You should share your code.

Comment: How did you get this error? Perhaps it's too broad unless there is a specific code being shown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GetPixel is a method on the Bitmap class, not the Image class. You can instantiate a Bitmap by providing an Image to the constructor. The problem isn't your using directives, it's that you're using the wrong class.

Comment: could you please tell me what is your suggestion for solving that problem?

Comment: Yes, I suggest that, outside your loop, you instantiate a Bitmap object from your Image object. Then you can count your pixels using that instead of the Image object itself.

Comment: but i have done that. see the edited code plz. its still giving the refrence error...

Comment: You're still storing your Bitmap as an Image. Try this, when you want to use GetPixel, cast your Image to a Bitmap:
    `((Bitmap)bmp).GetPixel(x, y)`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `bmp` is of type `System.Drawing.Image`, but the `GetPixel` method is only defined for `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: so do you mean i need to import that to my library?

Comment: my library does not have .Drawing.Bitmap

Comment: I do not understand, Image and Bitmap are both defined in System.Drawing.dll.